# Which licence covers all of Intune, Azure AD Premium and Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing, entra-id

Not sure if this is the right stackexchange forum for this question, but I am wanting to deploy Azure AD Premium, MS Intune and Office 365.  Is there one licence that covers all of these?

From what I can see, I would need Enterprise Mobility + Security E3 or Enterprise Mobility + Security E5 as well as an Office 365 account to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Azure Active Directory

There are four editions of Azure Active Directory (AAD).  Two of the editions are considered “Premium”.  The first ADD Premium plan is known as “Plan 1” and is included In O365 E3 or M365 E3.   The second AAD Premium plan is known as “Plan 2” and is included in O365 E5 or M365 E5.   The main difference between AAD Plan 1 and AAD Plan 2 is the ability to implement Privileged Identity Management (PIM).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

## Intune

Office 365 E3 does not include Intune.  However Microsoft 365 E3 does include Intune as well as the introductory enterprise mobility suite.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise-mobility-security/compare-plans-and-pricing

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/fundamentals/licenses

---

All components of Office 365 and Microsoft 365 can be purchased individual if they are not included in the plan as well.   For example, if you have Microsoft 365 E3 and also require AAD Premium Plan 2, AAD Premium Plan 2 can be added individually without going to the Microsoft 365 E5 plan.